# Is it possible to execute multiple inserts when one of the value parameters is dynamic?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following Postgresql database table:

```
id    | book_id |  author_id
----------------------------
 1    |  17     | 10
 2    |  18     | 10
 3    |  19     | 10
 4    |  22     | 10
```

I'd like to insert new author_id values into this table for book_id's where author_id=10. For example, the resulting table would resemble the following...

```
id    | book_id |  author_id
----------------------------
 1    |  17     | 10
 2    |  18     | 10
 3    |  19     | 10
 4    |  22     | 10
 5    |  17     | 11
 6    |  18     | 11
 7    |  19     | 11
 8    |  22     | 11
```

Without writing individual insert statements for each book_id, is it possible to write a single insert statement that would mimic the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Insert into table(book_id,author_id)
(
    Select table.book_id,11 FROM table
    Where author_id=10
)
```